# Move div down once past a certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to make '.pierre' .moveDown once the image has a left position of 20% but its not working. Whats supposed to happen is once the image has a left position of 20% it needs to fall down the page by itself. The html and css code is located in the fiddle.

Heres a link to a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Pallonej/0vhc7pqq/

this is my script thats not working

```
if ($('.pierre').css('left') == '20%') {
    $(this).moveDown();
}
```

Comment: are you trying to move it by your self or after the event of moving left finsihed. btw your right move doesn't work and slideDown is not what you expect what it is

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. For us to help you, you need to be clear about what you are expecting to see, and what is happening instead. Remember that what is inside your head isn't inside ours :) In this case, it's not clear what you mean by "its not working" ... what exactly would you like to happen? What do you observe happening instead? Are you getting any errors in the console? can you include the *relevant* html as well here? these things should all be a part of your original question - so can you please not add them as a comment, but instead edit your question and add them there.

Answer (score 2):

Your check for the position should be inside of the keydown handler and then parse the value from `$.css(..)` to an integer to have your comparison work.

The code could look like in the updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/0vhc7pqq/4/).

I've also added `stop` to you animation to avoid animation queuing. Maybe it's better to do this with-out animation.

With `$(document).width() * 0.2` you can calculate the relative position for the falling position.

If you want to hide or remove the box once it is fallen you can add a done callback to the animation to do what you're looking for. In the demo I've hidden the box.

```js
//move person
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { // left
        $(".pierre").stop(true,true).animate({
            left: "-=30"
        });

    } else if (e.keyCode == 37) { // right
        $(".pierre").stop(true,true).animate({
            left: "-=30"
        });
    }

    //console.log($('.pierre').css('left'));
    if (parseInt($('.pierre').css('left')) <= $(document).width() * 0.2 ) {
        //$(this).slideDown();
        $('.pierre').animate({
            top: "+=" + $(document).height()
        }, function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }
});

//fall
/*if ($('.pierre').css('left') === '+5px') {
    //$(this).slideDown();
     $(this).animate({
            left: "-=30"
        });
}*/
```

```css
.pierre {
    height:15%;
    width:15%;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 90%;
    top: -.7%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='pierre'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with the `offset`  property and not `position`

Here's an example for your question with extra feature to illustrate the concept :

```
    var position =  $(".pierre").offset();

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
 var y= $(".pierre").offset().top;
      var x = $(".pierre").offset().left;
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { // left

      $("#position").html("X: "+x+" , Y:"+y);


        $(".pierre").animate({
            left: "-=30"
        });


    } else if (e.keyCode == 37) { // right
        $(".pierre").animate({
            left: "+=30"
        });
    }



if (x<=200) {

     $(".pierre").animate({
            top: "+=30"
        });
}


});
```

and here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vhc7pqq/5/)

Answer (score 0):

As Alundra alreay mentioned, you should use `.offset()`.
You can add a callback to the `.animate` function, which will be executed after the animation has finished. If the location is right, you can call stop, in order to stop all current (and future) animation, so it won't move left again for the times you button-bashed left. Then you can again animate it to let it fall.
The new js code (I removed the second right-left button part for readability):

```
//move person
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { // left
        $(".pierre").animate({
            left: "-=30"
        }, function(){
            if($('.pierre').position().left < window.innerWidth/5){
                $('.pierre').stop(true);
                $('.pierre').animate({
                    top: "+=1000"
                });   
            }
        });
    }
});
```